# How to return more than one object from a ajax call (grails)

Tags: ajax, grails

I have an ajax function which should return a list of objects. I'm sorry for asking this i'm a beginner in grails and web programming

For example my ajax function should return the combination of this

```
def ajaxFunction= {
    //it should return all the following object
    List<String> stringList = ......
    List<ClassA> classAList = .....
    ClassB objectOfB = ....
    int count = ...
    .
    .
    .
    //I don't know who to return this all... (stringList , classAList , objectOfB ,count)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it better to creat a bean class. like this

```
class YourBeanClass {
    List<String> stringList;
    List<ClassA> classAList;
    ClassB objectOfB;
    int count;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

so you can use this bean class and return this bean class

```
def ajaxFunction= {
    YourBeanClass yourBeanClass = new YourBeanClass();
    yourBeanClass.stringList = ......
    yourBeanClass.classAList = .....
    yourBeanClass.objectOfB = ....
    yourBeanClass.count = ...
    yourBeanClass..
    .
    .

    //you can return/render this yourBeanClass
    return yourBeanClass

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do this:

```
def ajaxFunction= {
    //it should return all the following object
    List<String> stringList = ......
    List<ClassA> classAList = .....
    ClassB objectOfB = ....
    int count = ...
    return [stringList:stringList,classAList:classAList,objectOfB:objectOfB,count:count] as JSON

}
```

Just remember to import the grails converter JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple json objects and parse it at the client side :

```
List<String> stringList1 =  new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> stringList2 =  new ArrayList<String>();

String json1 = new Gson().toJson(stringList1); 
String json2 = new Gson().toJson(stringList2); 
String bothJson = "["+json1+","+json2+"]"; //Put both objects in an array of 2 elements

return bothJson as JSON
```

Not tested though.